# how to get a points sphere?

Tags: modeling

I would like to ask how to create a sphere composed of uniformly distributed points in edit mode. As shown in the picture, I made it using the points of a cube and an array modifier, but it’s not round enough when I manually adjust it. Is there any good method or idea?[image]

Comment: Why do you want to have single vertices, a mesh without faces? And what do you mean by "it's not round enough"? -- I would use Geometry Nodes: UV Sphere -> Mesh To Volume -> Distribute Points In Volume (Grid option). This will create a point cloud. It can be rendered in Cycles. If you want a mesh that has only vertices you need to put a single vert on each point and realize the instances with the *Instance on Points* and *Realize Instances* nodes.

Comment: thanks!i'll try it!